# How to query firebase data in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase data looks like these:

```
"worldwide" : [{
  "key1" : {
    "movie_id": 100,
    "release_date": 1524182400000,
    "description": "Cool movie here"
  },
  "key2" : {
    "movie_id": 101,
    "release_date": 1525046400000,
    "description": "Plot is cool"
  }
}]

"europe" : [{
  "key1" : {
    "movie_id": 100,
    "release_date": 1516798528489,
    "description": "Cool movie here"
  },
  "key3" : {
    "movie_id": 102,
    "release_date": 1525046400000,
    "description": "Cool plot"
  }
}]
```

Note: Both lists are inside a man list called *releases*

I've been trying for the past hours to query my data in java/android so that both data in both list join together to make one complete list with the movies ordered by release_date (which are in milliseconds) and for the duplicate entries I want the release_date information in the Europe array to take priority, so if the movie_id is in both list and it has a different release date in the worldwide array and the Europe array, I want the entry in the Europe array to be saved in in the complete list. For example, "movie_id": 100 appears in both list. Thank you.

My java code:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Query query = null; // I don't know how to structure my query
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot movie: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Any tips would be appreciated, like I'd like to hear if there's any better method to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Step one is to stop ignoring potentiontial errors: `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, you need to make sure that your database has the [correct](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) `.indexOn` [rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data). This will ensure that you can query/sort your data.

Next, you can add the Query to the database reference:

```
firebase::database::Query query =
reference.GetReference("worldwide").OrderByChild("release_date");
```

Finally, Read up on the [Sorting/Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) from the documentation.

---

To merge the two lists, just run two queries and add the movies into a concurrent list.  Then sort the list.

Comment: I just had a weird thought.. if both lists are sorted, then store the lists separately, then run a merge sort (into a queue).

Comment: So I'll have to join the two lists in java?

Comment: If your keys are unique, then you could just merge the two lists into another master/merged list.  Typically, Firebase Database structure is very flat, and duplicate data is not a problem.  You could make a Cloud Function that automatically propagates new children into the master/merge.  But yeah, that or just merge them in Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is no construct in Firebase to read data from both lists with one query. This means that you will have to:

- *either* use two listeners (one on `worldwide` and one on `europe`) and merge the results from those listeners in the client.
- *or* use a single listener at the node *above* `worldwide` and `europe` and then iterate over the resulting snapshot.

The latter is simpler in code, but might be less efficient.

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot movie: dataSnapshot.getChild("europe").getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(movie.getKey()+": "+movie.getChild("movie_id").getValue());
        }
        for (DataSnapshot movie: dataSnapshot.getChild("worldwide").getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(movie.getKey()+": "+movie.getChild("movie_id").getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw new databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```